# Filter with multiple criteria in Mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In Mongo (specifically pymongo), my goal is to be able to exclude records which are not equal to one of many values. In this example, where the data is not 504 or 400. I know that I can exclude records which do not contain a single value using:

```
foo = db.collection.find({
        "data": { "$ne": 400 }
    })
```

And I have tried:

```
foo = db.collection.find({
        "data": { "$ne": 400 },
        "data": { "$ne": 504 }
    })
```

and

```
foo = db.collection.find({
        "data": { "$ne": 400, "$ne": 504 }
    })
```

...but in both cases, it appears that only the last comparison takes place. I still get records where data is 400. How can I write this so that it filters on both? In other words, how can I perform a "data is not equal to any of the following [...]"?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nin/

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/) of the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You are looking for `$nin`.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nin/),

> `$nin` selects the documents where:
>
> - the `field` value is not in the specified array or
> - the `field` does not exist.

Try

```
foo = db.collection.find({
    "data": { "$nin": [504, 400] },
})
```